# How to create dataframe from ordered dictionary?

Tags: ordereddict

I have an ordered dictionary which has 4 keys and multiple values. I tried to create the dataframe like this

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(items, index=[0])
  print('\ndf is ',df)
```

But this triggers ValueError, as the multiple values from the dictionary don't match.
The ordered dictionary is below:

```
OrderedDict([('Product', 'DASXZSDASXZS'), ('Region', ['A', 'B', 'C']), ('Items', ['1', '2', '3']), ('Order', ['123', '456', '789'])])
```

I want the dataframe format to be like:

```
Product      Region Items Order
DASXZSDASXZS A      1     123
DASXZSDASXZS B      2     456
              ...
```

How can I achieve this format for the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough rep to comment. Why do you try to specify `index=[0]`?
Simply doing

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
```

works; if you want to change the index, you can set it later with `df.set_index(...)`

Answer (score 1):

@viktor_dmitry your comment to @Battleman links to external data, here's a solution.

In https://www.codepile.net/pile/GY336DYN you have a `list` of `OrderedDict` entries, in the example above you just had 1 `OrderedDict`. Each needs to be treated as a separate `DataFrame` construction. From the resulting list you use `concat` to get a final `DataFrame`:

```
ods = [OrderedDict([('MaterialNumber', '2XV9450-1AR24'), ('ForCountry'...]), 
       OrderedDict([('MaterialNumber', ...), 
       ...]
new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(od) for od in ods])
# new_df has 4 columns and many rows
```

Note also that 1 of your example items is invalid, you'd need to filter this out, the rest appear to be fine:

```
ods[21]
OrderedDict([('MaterialNumber', '4MC9672')]) # lacks the rest of the columns!
```